# O que está de errado neste método?

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um método de adicionar Usuários, e apenas uma coisa não está funcionando, a função que:

> "Não será permitido adicionar amigos com o mesmo número de celular."

Ai precisa checar os usuários já adicionados, para ver se eles não tem um número de celular igual ao que for adicionado.
Ele está adicionando, mas também está adicionando os usuários com o número de celular igual. E não poderia adicionar se o número fosse igual

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 public void AdicionaAmigo(Usuario usr)
    {
       boolean existeEsteNum = false;
       if(ListadeAmigos == null || ListadeAmigos.length == 0) { 

         for(int i=0; i<ListadeAmigos.length; i++){
            if(ListadeAmigos[i].getCel() == usr.getCel()){
                existeEsteNum = true;
                System.out.println ("Já existe um usuário cadastrado com esse número de celular");
                break;
                }
         }
       } 

       if(!existeEsteNum){
           if(qtdeAmigos < ListadeAmigos.length)
           {
            ListadeAmigos[qtdeAmigos++] = usr;
            System.out.println ("Usuario adicionado com sucesso!");
           } else {
            System.out.println ("A lista está cheia");
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione o código em forma de texto, para facilitar que seja testado.

Comment: E qual é o erro que retorna?

Comment: E informe o que não está funcionando. O que acontece? Em que circunstâncias acontece?

Comment: Ele está adicionando, mas também está adicionando os usuários com o número de celular igual. E não poderia adicionar se o número fosse igual.

Comment: A parte de verificar o celular não está funcionando, ele adiciona de qualquer maneira os usuários;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que está errado neste método, é que você está percorrendo o "for" se a lista está vazia, logo não vai cair na condição nunca.

O que você deve fazer é revisar o primeiro IF o correto seria:

```
if ( ListadeAmigos != null && ListadeAmigos.length > 0 )
```

Comment: Acabei de tentar fazer assim, deu a mensagem de erro "java.lang.NullPointerException: null" e marcando em amarelo o  if(ListadeAmigos[i].getCel() == usr.getCel()){

Comment: Então veja se `usr` está nulo ou se tem alguma posição na lista que está nula. A resposta está correta.

Comment: @Daniel, quando não se tem certeza se você possui valor preenchido, você nunca deve acessar direto, pois causará o nullPointerException, verifique antes de acessar o getCel() se o usr ou ListadeAmigos[i] não está nulo

Comment: Entendi a lógica. Mas como posso fazer?

Comment: if ( ( usr != null && ListadeAmigos[i] != null) && ListadeAmigos[i].getCel() == usr.getCel() )

Comment: Primeiro você verifica se existe os objetos (não estão nulos) e depois verifica se os celulares são iguais

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trocar esse "==" no if `ListadeAmigos[i].getCel() == usr.getCel()`por equals(), creio que ficaria melhor, o "==" testa a referência, e não o valor. Essa seria a primeira coisa que vi logo de cara, vou dar mais umas olhadas e ver se encontro algo.
[Esse aqui é um exemplo e explicação dessas comparações](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!